# Nginx can't switch root folder on ubuntu linux aws ec2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, nginx-location

I am trying to switch the root file location for my nginx server.  I have had this issue in the past for a couple months but gave up every time and just manually moved new html, css and javascript files into /var/www/html but now im developing ci/cd and need to know how to change the root folder.  Thanks.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /home/ubuntu/test_root;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}
```

Comment: Look at the file owners and permission. Compare with /var/www folder. Probably they will like www-data i dont know.

Comment: It is not about ec2 it is about linux ubuntu nginx installation. Search according to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like permissions just needed to be changed for files.
For future reference
chmod 755 for all directories leading up to nginx root
that is rwx-rx-rx
where the user and group is root big thank you to @rmznbyk 1